# JavaDoc fails with "Illegal package name"-error

Tags: java, javadoc

I am using Eclipse and have 8 packages in my Java project. I try to generate my javadoc with Eclipse (Project->Generate JavaDoc).. but after I start the process the following errors appears:

```
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.4.200.v20130515-1857.jar;C:UsersPhilworkspaceBachelor_Thesislibjunit-4.10.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopEclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "s\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.text_3.5.300.v20130515-1451.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255.jar;C:UsersPhilworkspaceBachelor_Thesisliblog4j-1.2.17.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopEclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "s\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jface_3.9.0.v20130521-1714.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.105.0.v20130529-1406.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopEclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "s\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.102.0.v20130605-1544.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopEclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "s\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.300.v20130327-1442.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.ui.forms_3.6.0.v20130517-0139.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopEclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "s\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\BALokal\ZipsUndJars\antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.core.databinding.beans_1.2.200.v20130515-1857.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopEclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "s\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.100.v20130515-1857.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopBALokalZipsUndJarseaapi.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopEclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "s\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jface.text_3.8.100.v20130515-1957.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.6.200.v20130515-1857.jar;C:UsersPhilDesktopEclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "s\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.4.1.v20130515-1857.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse"
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "sjavaeclipseeclipsepluginsorg.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.1.v20130515-1857.jar -private -source 1.7 -use -version -author -splitindex controller "
```

Anybody have a solution for this problem? I use the WindowBuilder in Eclipse to create my GUI. It seems that all the named jar's in the errors are windowbuilder jar's.

Here is my ant file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="javadoc">
  <target name="javadoc">
    <javadoc access="private" author="true" classpath="C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_1.4.200.v20130515-1857.jar;lib/junit-4.10.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.text_3.5.300.v20130515-1451.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.9.0.v20130326-1255.jar;lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jface_3.9.0.v20130521-1714.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.105.0.v20130529-1406.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.icu_50.1.1.v201304230130.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.102.0.v20130605-1544.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.300.v20130327-1442.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.6.0.v20130517-0139.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\BALokal\ZipsUndJars\antlr-4.2.2-complete.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans_1.2.200.v20130515-1857.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.100.v20130515-1857.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\BALokal\ZipsUndJars\eaapi.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jface.text_3.8.100.v20130515-1957.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.6.200.v20130515-1857.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.4.1.v20130515-1857.jar;C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\Eclipse's\javaeclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_1.4.1.v20130515-1857.jar" destdir="C:\Users\Phil\Desktop\BT_JavaDoc" nodeprecated="false" nodeprecatedlist="false" noindex="false" nonavbar="false" notree="false" packagenames="ea_xml_parser,gui,tsql_parser,controller,ea_activity_diagram,start_application,test" source="1.7" sourcepath="src" splitindex="true" use="true" version="true"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

**Edit(Solution)**

With the help from the comments under my question I have solved the problem. In the path of my first `build_path` entry a folder was named "Eclipse's". Without an apostrophe it works! :-)

Comment: I strongly suspect that having an apostrophe in your directory name (`Eclipse's`) is doing you no favours at all here...

Comment: I'd omit the classpath="...". There's no need to make all those eclipse jars and their classes visible to javadoc. It'll look at the sources (below .\src\) and that's it.

Comment: I suspect that the error messages aren't from that ant target definition. "Bachelor_Thesis" occurs twice in the error messages, but isn't in that ant XML.

Comment: thank you for your answers! I think the Eclipse's-Foldername was the problem. Now it work's. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Instead of editing your question, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the answers in the comments below of my question. With the help from these comments  I had solve the problem.

In the path of my first build_path entry a folder was named "Eclipse's". Without apostrophes it work's!:-)