# How to customize "Overview" page in JavaDoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'd like the "**Overview**" page of my library's javadoc to essentially be a user/API guide for the entire JAR. I know that adding a `package-info.java` class to a package allows you to write *package-level* javadocs, but what about at the *jar-level*?

I know I could put a `README.md` in my project's root, but I like to think of README's as a doc for library developers (that is, people who will be *maintaining* the library). But the JavaDocs are API guides for people who will be *using* the library.

Comment: Why don't you put a `README.md` for the JavaDoc and a `README.whateveryoulike` for the maintainers?

Comment: Probably because I like @Flic's answer :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create an overview HTML file and place it anywhere you like in your source tree.  The convention is to call it overview.html and place it at the root of your tree, but you are certainly not obligated to do so.  In fact, you can create multiple overview files for different purposes.  When you generate your javadocs, you use the -overview flag and pass it the path to the target overview file.

You can find more information about overview file requirements [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#overviewcomment).

Comment: This is true, but does adding a overview.html file override all of the existing automatically-generated HTML? I just want to add some text, not have to redo the automatically-generated links. Thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I see. Just tried it. It adds the HTML file's content to the existing HTML file. It does not override it.

Comment: I have my overview.html file in my src directory. When I use the -overview flag, Eclipse tells me JavaDoc: error - illegal package name: <path to file is here>?

Comment: @Andrew S - without seeing the full error output, it's hard to diagnose the problem but it doesn't sound like an overview issue.  Maybe check out this answer for inspiration:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848404/javadoc-fails-with-illegal-package-name-error.  Hope it helps!

Comment: @Flic, it turned out I had the compiler set to Java8 which did not understand this.

Comment: @Andrew S Interesting....  Thanks for the update - it's always worthwhile to check out the environment config.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using Maven and its [plugin for JavaDoc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin):

Put a file named `overview.html` into folder `src/main/javadoc` and run the command `mvn javadoc:javadoc`; the JavaDoc files are written into folder `target/site/apidocs`.

This is also possible when you want to generate JavaDoc files for the Unit Tests: Put a file named `overview.html` into folder `src/test/javadoc` and run the command `mvn javadoc:test-javadoc`; the JavaDoc files are written into folder `target/site/testapidocs`.